# SQL - Inner Join and Columns to Rows

Tags: mysql, sql

Using MySQL and I have two tables similar to the following. Both actually have more rows and more columns but for ease of reading, I've only put a few

**wp_ahm_files**

```
ID | Field_A | Field_B | Field_C
--------------------------------
69 | ABC     | DEF     | GHI
```

**wp_ahm_filemeta**

pID in this table refers to the ID of the table above

```
ID | pID | Name    | Value
---------------------------------
25 | 69  | Version | 12345
26 | 69  | Expiry  | 29/08/1981
```

How do I bring back a resultset such as

```
ID | Field_A | Field_B | Field_C | Version | Expiry
-------------------------------------------------------
69 | ABC     | DEF     | GHI     | 12345   | 29/08/1981
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should be able to JOIN to your `wp_ahm_filemeta` twice to get the result:

```
select f.id,
  f.field_a,
  f.field_b,
  f.field_c,
  m1.value version,
  m2.value expiry
from wp_ahm_files f
left join wp_ahm_filemeta m1
  on f.id = m1.pid
  and m1.name = 'Version'
left join wp_ahm_filemeta m2
  on f.id = m2.pid
  and m2.name = 'Expiry';
```

See [SQL Fiddle with Demo](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/21f006/1). The key is to place a filter on the JOIN condition to return the rows with the specific `name` value you want.

You could also convert the rows of data into columns by using an aggregate function with a CASE expression:

```
select f.id,
  f.field_a,
  f.field_b,
  f.field_c,
  max(case when m.name = 'Version' then m.value end) version,
  max(case when m.name = 'Expiry' then m.value end) expiry
from wp_ahm_files f
left join wp_ahm_filemeta m
  on f.id = m.pid
group by f.id, f.field_a, f.field_b, f.field_c;
```

See [SQL Fiddle with Demo](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/21f006/2)

Answer (score 1):

Something like

```
  select a.*, version.value version, expiry.value expiry
  from a join 
  ( select * from b where name = 'Version' ) version
  on version.table_a_id = a.id
  join 
  ( select * from b where name = 'Expiry' ) expiry
  on expiry.table_a_id = a.id
```

Comment: Sorry, I get nothing back. I've changed the question with the actual table names. If I leave one of the joins in ONLY then it works. With both, nothing

Comment: check what the subqueries return- for example: select * from b where name = 'Expiry'